# Python Tkinter show image acessed on a listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm trying to make a python script that shows a image that is acessed on a listbox. This code that I got on the internet works:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = tk.Tk()

path = 'img\\2015722_univ_sqs_sm.jpg'
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(window, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

window.mainloop()
```

But when I tried to adapt it do the listbox it stopped working.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import glob

files = glob.glob('img\\*.jpg')

class App:

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.l = Listbox(root, width = 50, height = 15)
        self.l.pack()
        self.l.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.lol)

        self.c = Label(root)
        self.c.pack()

        for f in files:
            self.l.insert(END, f)

    def lol(self, evt):

        path = files[self.l.curselection()[0]]
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        self.c.image = img
        self.c.pack()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can we see the error message?

Comment: no errors, simply don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the `configure` method of the label, and store a reference to the image somewhere.

```
self.c.image = img           # save reference
self.c.configure(image=img)  # configure the label
```